# Using processing and getting this error

Tags: java, processing

Have this processing basic game I've been working on and I keep getting this "expecting EOF, found 'YoshiXDX'" error. Can anyone spot the error in my code? Am new to this whole processing ordeal and I know I should place all my variables first so that they're in the scope of draw and setup but I guess I must have screwed up elsewhere.

```
Many thanks,

/* @pjs preload="peach-castle.jpg","Yoshi.png","Fireball.png"; */


int FireballX, FireballY;
int YoshiX, YoshiY;
int YoshiXdX, YoshiYdY;
YoshiXdX= 5;
YoshiYdY = 5;
int FireballXdX, FireballYdY;
FireballXDX = 8; 
FireballYdY = 8;
Pimage Fireball, background, Yoshi; 
int randompos;
float timeStarted;
int FireballPoints, YoshiPoints;
FireballPoints = 0;
YoshiPoints = 0;
boolean spawn1 = true;
float distance = dist(FireballX, FireballY, YoshiX, YoshiY);



    void setup()
{
  size(500, 500);
  noCursor();
  background(0);
  timeStarted = millis();
  Fireball = loadImage("Fireball.png");
  Yoshi = loadImage("Yoshi.png");
  background = loadImage("peach-castle.jpg");
  imageMode(CENTER);
  //image(background, 0, 0, width, height);
}



    void draw()
{

  long currentTime = millis();
  long elapsedTime = (currentTime - timeStarted)/1000;
  text("# of Yoshi's points: " YoshiPoints, 20, 15);
  text("# of Fireball's points: " FireballPoints, 20, 30);
  text("Time played: "+ elapsedTime, 20, 45);

  if (spawn1 == true){
   Respawn();
   image(Fireball, FireballX, FireballY);
   image(Yoshi, YoshiX, YoshiY); 
   spawn1 == false;}

  Main();
}

void Wrapcheck() {  

  if (FireballX> width) {
    FireballX = FireballX - width;
  } 
  if (FireballX < 0 ) {
    FireballX = height+ FireballX ;
  } 
  if (FireballY > height) {
    FireballY = FireballY - height;
  }
  if (FireballY < 0 ) {
    FireballY = height - FireballY;
  }
}

void Yoshimoves() {
  if ((FireballX - YoshiX)> 0) {
    YoshiX -= YoshiXdX;
  } else if ((FireballX - YoshiX)<0) {
    YoshiX += YoshiXdX;
  } else if ((FireballY - YoshiY)>0) {
    YoshiY += YoshiYdY;
  } else if ((FireballY - YoshiY)<0) {
    YoshiY -= YoshiYdY;
  }
}

void keyPressed()
{
  if (key == 'w') {
    FireballY += FireballYdY;
  }
  if (key == 's') {
    FireballY -= FireballYdY;
  }
  if (key == 'd') {
    FireballX += FireballXdX
  }
  if (key == 'a') {
    FireballX -= FireballXdX
  }

  Yoshimoves();
}

void collision() {

  if (distance <= 50) {
    FireballPoints ++;
    Respawn();
  }
}

void Yoshicheck() {
  if ((YoshiX> width) || (YoshiX>0) || (YoshiY>height) || (YoshiY<0)) {
    YoshiPoints++;
    Respawn();
  }
}


void Respawn() {

  randompos = random(0, 3);
  if (randompos == 0) {
    FireballX, FireballY = width/2, 25;
  } else if (randompos == 1) {
    FireballX, FireballY = width-25, height/2
  } else if (randompos == 2) {
    FireballX, FireballY = width/2, height-25;
  } else if (randompos == 3) {
    FireballX, FireballY = 25, height/2
  } 
  YoshiX, YoshiY = width/2, height/2;
}

void Main() {

  Wrapcheck();
  collision();
  Yoshicheck();
}
```

Comment: Please, **PLEASE** use naming convention and indentation correctly. As for your problem, you have many lines missing semicolons and variable initialisation not in the actual statement or an instance initialiser; apart from that, from the standard of your code, you really need a Java tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are writing Java code, did you define all this in a 'class'?

Answer (score 0):

The line near the top

YoshiXdX= 5;

is the source of the error. This declares no type for YoshiXdX and instead needs to be

int YoshiXdX= 5;

There are several instances of missing types in your declarations. If you just fix this one the very next line will give you the same sort of error. As bcsb1001 indicated, these all need fixing before you can even try to run this. And all the lines ending without a ; need fixing too. The bytecode compiler doesn't know what to do with lines that have syntax errors like these.

The very first few tutorials at processing.org explain these things, or take a lot at any beginning Java site/book. Whatever language you use, getting the syntax right on every line is the first step in getting your code to work. Processing uses a simplified Java, but not quite that simplified. Unfortunately, the Processing IDE is very simple and not very helpful in this regard. I real IDE like Eclipse would warn you of these errors as soon as you typed them...